# Adjoint of a linear isomorphic functional is an isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

I have this exercise to solve:

> Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces and let $T \in L(E,F)$, where $L(E,F)$ denotes the set of all bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$. $T^*$ is the dual operator of $T$ with $T^*: F^* \to E^*$ and $T^*\varphi=\varphi \circ T$. Assume $T$ is an isomorphism, i.e. $T$ is bijective and $T^{-1}\in L(F,E)$. Prove that $T^*$ is also an isomorphism and $(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*$.

**My work**

- Proof of $(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*$:

We know that $(T \circ G)^*= T^*\circ G^*$ since $((T \circ G)^*\varphi)(x)=\varphi((T\circ G)(x))=(G^*\varphi)(Tx)=((T^*\circ G^*)\varphi)(x)$

Now plug in $T^*$ and $(T^{-1})^*$ to the equation, we have:

$T^*\circ (T^{-1})^* = (T\circ T^{-1})^*= Id^* = Id$ and $(T^{-1})^* \circ T^* = (T^{-1}\circ T)^*= Id^* = Id$

Hence, $(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*$.

- Proof of isomorphism:

  Injectivity:

Let $\varphi$ and $\psi \in F^*$. Let $T^*\varphi=T^*\psi$ then we have $\varphi \circ T=\psi \circ T$. Here can I conclude that since $T$ bijective we have $\varphi = \psi$?

It remains to prove the surjectivity and I'm still struggling with this part.

Comment: Think about it the other way around: show that $(T^{-1})^*$ acts like the inverse to $T^*$.

Comment: Note: "functional", in the context of linear algebra, usually means a linear transformation whose image is in the field of scalars (viewed as a vector space). You should not use it as a synonym for "function".

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question and added some more work. Could anyone please tell if it's correct? And it would be really helpful with some more precise hints.

Comment: I believe the surjectivity may depend on whether you're considering algebraic or topological duals.  In the former case, if $\ \lambda \in E^*\ $ and 
$\ \varphi = \lambda T^{-1}\ $, then $\ T^*\varphi = \lambda\ $, but if $\ T^{-1}\ $ isn't bounded, then $\varphi\ $ will not necessarily lie in the topological dual of $\ F\ $.  If your spaces were Banach spaces, then the bounded inverse theorem guarantees that $\ T^{-1}\ $ is bounded, and you're home.  But if your spaces are not complete I don't believe the result holds for topological duals without some extra assumption.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera - That $T^{-1}$ is bounded is part of the hypothesis: "Assume $T$ is an isomorphism, i.e. $T$ is bijective and $T^{−1}\in L(F,E)$".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, thank you. I obviously missed the fact that $\ L(F,E)\ $ had been defined as a set of *bounded* linear operators.

Answer (score 1):

Hong thank you for tagging me in the other question: [Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, show that if they are isomorphic, then $X$ is reflexive iff $Y$ is reflexive.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271817/let-x-and-y-be-banach-spaces-show-that-if-they-are-isomorphic-then-x-is/971075?noredirect=1#comment6661629_971075)
But the answer is just that $(f^{-1})^*=(f^*)^{-1}$ and $f^*$ linear.

Do you need to see either of these facts spelled out further?  The point is that $f^*$ is an isomorphism if and only if $(f^*)^{-1}$ is continuous (or more generally, $g:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism if and only if $g^{-1}$ is continuous). But continuity is equivalent to being bounded.  So we just have to show that $(f^{-1})^*$ is bounded.  Does that clarify things?

See this for example:
http://mathonline.wikidot.com/isomorphism-linear-operators-on-normed-linear-spaces

Comment: Isn't it insufficient just to show that $(f^{−1})^∗$  is bounded? Theorem 2 in the second link says: A **bijective** bounded linear operator $T:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism if and only if $T^{−1}$ is continuous. So I think bijectivity of $f^*$ should also be proven.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for surjectivity:

Let $\psi \in E^*$ be arbitrary.  You need to find a functional $\varphi \in F^*$ such that $T^* \varphi = \psi$.  That is, such that $\varphi \circ T = \psi$.  Can you guess how to define a functional $\varphi$ that might work?  You'll have to verify that your guess works, and that it's actually a continuous functional.