# Non-isomorphic Banach space to a given one

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is a seaprable Banach infinite-dimensional is it possible to construct another separable Banach space infinite-dimensional $Y$ such that is not isomorphic to $X$?

Comment: If $X$ has  a Schauder basis then take any separable (infinite dimensional) space without a Schauder basis . If $X$ does not have  a Schauder basis then take any (infinite dimensional) separable space with a Schauder basis .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually generalize what Kavi Rama Murthy is saying: there are many properties that are "invariants" under isomorphisms of Banach spaces, i.e. continuous linear bijections. The property of having a Schauder Basis is one of them.

Your question is the same as asking if there exists a property that is "invariant" under isomorphisms that some infinite dimensional, separable Banach spaces have but some other spaces don't.

The question is not as innocent as it seems: for example, one could start by considering the algebraic dimension as such a property; this is invariant under isomorphisms of vector spaces, but it can actually be proved (using Baire's category theorem) that every infinite dimensional, separable Banach space has dimension equal to $\frak{c}$.

The existence of an infinite dimensional, separable Banach space that does not have a Schauder basis is no child's play: Per Enflo constructed such a space many years after the question was first asked.

I think another invariant property that is easier to consider is that of reflexivity: we say that a Banach space $X$ is *reflexive* if the canonical (isometric) embedding $j:X\to X^{**}$ given by $j(x)=\text{ev}_x$ is surjective (where $\text{ev}_x$ is the evaluation functional at $x$, i.e. $\text{ev}_x(\phi)=\phi(x)$).

To make sure that this is an invariant property, see this [very nice post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271817/let-x-and-y-be-banach-spaces-show-that-if-they-are-isomorphic-then-x-is/971075?noredirect=1#comment6661629_971075) and we can discuss it if anything is unclear. Basically you start with a bounded linear isomorphism $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces and you show that the double adjoint map $T^{**}:X^{**}\to Y^{**}$ is also an isomorphism of Banach spaces. You then assume that $X$ is reflexive to conclude that the canonical embedding of $Y\to Y^{**}$ is also surjective and thus $Y$ is also reflexive.

Now it is very easy to find an infinite dimensional separable Banach space that is reflexive and another one that is not: simply take $\ell^2$ and $\ell^1$. It is well known that $\ell^2$ is reflexive but $\ell^1$ is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer. In fact, just after Kavi Rama Murthy posted his answer I immediately thought about reflexivity as you stated and how my question was a little bit stupid. But nevertheless his answer and yours made me read a little bit more about Schauder basis and learn some new things ;)